# Null reference exception c++

Tags: c++-cli

I keep getting this error in the console:

> Unhandled exception: System.NullReferenceException

Here's the code:

```
class Car {
public:
   int X;
   int Y;
};

class SpecificCar : public Car {

};

class Container {
public:
   int AmountOfCars = 0;
   Car **cars = nullptr;
   void AddCar(Car *ptr);
};

void Container::AddCar(Car *ptr) {
    if(AmountOfCars == 0) {
    cars[0] = ptr; //Debbuger says that the problem in question is located here
    AmountOfCars++;
    }

int main() {
    Container container;
    Car *ptr = new SpecificCar;
    ptr->X = 1;
    ptr->Y = 5;
    container.AddCar(ptr);
}
```

Comment: `cars` is null, but you're trying to use it. Forget the pointer nonsense and use `std::vector`.

Comment: That's the whole point of this thing. I don't want to use vector.

Comment: Then you need to allocate some memory for `cars` to point to.

Comment: You're absolutely right... Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious this is plain C++ code compiled as C++/CLI (and I suppose this is not intentional). I've added the C++ tag back.

Comment: @Deduplicator please read my comment above, I won't fight over this but I believe OP *really* wanted plain C++ here.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Interesting revision-history, I hadn't seen that. But *why* did you neither revert the re-tagging if you are convinced it was in error, nor left it alone if it wasn't? Adding a second conflicting language-tag doesn't make it any better...

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, I should have reverted it in the first place. Let's call it a brain fart. I've thought the OP would tell if he meant C++ or C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

While your `Container` by design isn't storing `Car`s, it still has to store pointers to cars. You'll have to come up with a method. The Standard offers `std::vector<Car>` as well as `std::vector<Car*>` but you're free to come up with anything else. Still, if you don't want the Standard methods, it's really up to you what else you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Car **cars` is not a dynamic container, it's a pointer to a memory region. What you did there is just utterly wrong. You still have to allocate an array of pointers to be able to fill data there, such as

```
cars = new Car*[5];
```

With that you can address with indices from 0 to 4 inside array `cars[]`. Yet again this is not dynamic, your best bet is an `std::vector<Car*>`, if you want to go your own ways then `malloc()`/`realloc()`, maybe linked listing if you really want to bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in class `Container`, you defined a member `cars` initialized to `nullptr`.

The best way to fix the issue is to use a `std::vector<Car*>` for `cars`. If you absolutely don't want to use a vector (why ?), in class `Container`, you may replace:

```
Car **cars = nullptr;
```

by something like:

```
static const int MAX_AMOUNT_OF_CARS = 100;
Car* cars[MAX_AMOUNT_OF_CARS];
```

which will define a proper array of `Car*`; then, you will be able to use `cars[0]`, `cars[i]`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I figure you're trying to teach yourself about memory management. I've rewritten your class and `AddCar()` to be more what you want. Accessing or removing a car and deleting the container are left as an exercise for the student. (Look at this as pseudo-code. I haven't compiled or run it.)

```
    class Container 
    {
            Car ** cars_ = nullptr;
            int capacity_ = 0;      // how much room we have for car pointers
            int AmountOfCars_ = 0;  // how many car pointers we actually contain
        public:
            int AmountOfCars() const { return AmountOfCars_; }
            void AddCar(Car *ptr);
    };

    void Container::AddCar(Car *ptr) 
    {
        if ( AmountOfCars_ + 1 > capacity_ ) // ensure we have capacity for another Car *
        {
            if ( capacity_ == 0 ) // if we have none set to 2, so we'll initially allocate room for 4
                capacity_ = 2;
            int newcapacity = capacity_ * 2;                    // double the capacity
            Cars ** newcars = new Car*[ newcapacity ];          // allocate a new pointer array
            memcpy( newcars, cars_, capacity_ * sizeof(Car*) ); // we're just moving pointers
            delete cars_;                                       // get rid of the old pointer array
            cars_ = newcars;                                    // point to the new pointer array
            capacity_ = newcapacity;                            // update the capacity
        }
        ++AmountOfCars_;                                        // increase the number of cars
        cars[ AmountOfCars_ ] = ptr;                            // and copy the pointer into the slot
    }
```

Comment: In the real world, you'd use a `std::vector`. You'd be a fool to write container code yourself for a real project.